# php - MySql select from table with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database, request

I need to select all from database when "main=1" once, then select all from database when "main=0" and use them **within the same request**. Can I do this in one request?
this is the request

1.

```
$result = $apt->query("SELECT * FROM cat where main='0'");

while($row=$apt->dbarray($result)){

@extract($row);
```

2.

```
$result = $apt->query("SELECT * FROM cat where main='1'");

while($row=$apt->dbarray($result)){

@extract($row);
```

I kind of need to combine them in one request because this will make a conflict when do 2 request.
Thanks

Comment: you can create function where you can pass the value of conditional parameter "main"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options

```
SELECT * from cat where main = '0' or main ='1';
```

or

```
SELECT * from cat where main in ('0','1');
```

If what you meant by a conflict is in reference to maintaining concurrency between the two queries, this way and wrapping the entire operation in a transaction are the only ways to ensure concurrency.

Here is an example of how you can use the queries above to emulate the code you provided but doing it in a single query.

```
  $result = $apt->query("SELECT * FROM cat where main='0' or main = '1' order by main");
  while($row=$apt->dbarray($result)){
        @extract($row);
        switch ($main){
            case 0:
                // do stuff for when main = 0
                break;
            case 1:
                // do stuff for when main = 1
                break;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, But I need to use main as 1 once then use it as 0 once within the same request. Any help?

Comment: it appears as though that is what you are doing in your question. You seem to be affraid of some kind of conflict... can you describe a situation where such a conflict would arise?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create 1 array and insert the result inside that array.

```
$array = array();
$result = $apt->query("SELECT * cat where main='0'");

while($row=$apt->dbarray($result)){
    $array['main0'][]  = $row[];
}

$result = $apt->query("SELECT * cat where main='1'");

while($row=$apt->dbarray($result)){
    $array['main1'][]  = $row[];
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

2) OR you can use 1 query with `IN`

```
$result = $apt->query("SELECT * cat where main IN ('0','1')");

while($row=$apt->dbarray($result)){
    $array['main0'][]  = $row[];
}
```